# NameError: global name 'query' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I have a small django project and Im trying to pass a variable from my views.py into tasks.py and run a task using the variable, but I am getting name is not defined error, ive tried many solutions ive seen on other questions but i cannot seem to get it to work

here is my views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render, loader
from django.template import Context
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
import requests
from tasks import rti

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'bus/index.html')

def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    t = loader.get_template('bus/search.html')
    c = Context({ 'query': query,})
    rti()
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

here is my tasks.py

```
from background_task import background
import time


@background(schedule=1)
def rti():
    timeout = time.time() + 60 * 15
    while time.time() < timeout:
        from views import search
        dblink = '*apiurl*' + str(query) + '&format=json'
        savelink = 'bus/static/bus/stop' + str(query)+ '.json'
        r = requests.get(dblink)
        jsondata = json.loads(r.text)
        with open(savelink, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(jsondata, f)
```

here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dylankilkenny/dev/python/test2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/background_task/tasks.py", line 49, in bg_runner
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/dylankilkenny/dev/python/test2/mysite/bus/tasks.py", line 9, in rti
    from views import search
NameError: global name 'query' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change defining of your method to `def rti(query):` and use it in view `rti(query)`, because you background task don't know anything about your query variable inside.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your task so that it takes the query as an argument.

```
@background(schedule=1)
def rti(query):
    ...
```

Then pass the query when you call the task in your view

```
rti(query)
```

Comment: ive tried this and got this error: `TypeError: rti() takes no arguments (1 given)`

Comment: That sounds as if the method has not been updated to `def rti(query)`. Make sure you have restarted the process that is running the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed any argument to the method `rti()` that you have called inside `views.py`. And to do that, while defining the method `rti()` inside `tasks.py`, the method should take an argument like query. After that you will be able to use `query` inside `rti()`.

Please follow these:

tasks.py:

```
@background(schedule=1)
def rti(query):
    {...your code}
```

views.py:

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    t = loader.get_template('bus/search.html')
    c = Context({ 'query': query,})
    rti(query)     #calling rti from tasks.py passing the argument
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```